# Accessing Eval() from codebehind after DataBind

Tags: asp.net, gridview, eval, late-binding

I have a GridView where the ItemTemplates are just Eval("ColumnName"), how can I access this field after the data has been bound?

I tried gv.Rows[0].Cells[0] etc. but there is nothing there.

Is this because of late binding? or is it just because the Eval is not in a control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out:

```
((DataBoundLiteralControl)gv.Rows[0].Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the data in the event 'RowCommand' or 'RowDataBind'?

Comment: it doesn't matter to me, just as long as I can access it somehow